# Check if URL = Desired URL (PHP)

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to check if the current URL equals the desired URL for making the link class `active` (Bootstrap).

Example

```
<?php
    If ($currenturl = "show.php?name=123") {
      ?><li class="active"><a href="show.php?name="123"">123</a></li><?php
    }else{
        ?><li class=""><a href="show.php?name="123"">123</a></li><?php
    }
?>
```

Current URL -> `$currenturl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Now, I have this if I'm on `show.php?name=456`

[image: see]

Comment: basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct comparison inside the `if`. You're currently using the assignment operator:

Note the difference:

```
if($currenturl = "show.php?name=123") // assignment =
  // changes $currenturl to "show.php?name=123"
  // and then tests if("show.php?name=123") equivalent to if(true)
  // see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940626/evaluation-of-assignment-in-php

if($currenturl == "show.php?name=123") // comparison ==
```

Second: You have set `$urlpage` but comparing `$currenturl`. Use `$urlpage`

Code:

```
<?php $urlpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
<?php if ($urlpage == "/show.php?nom=123") { ?>
    <li class="active"><a href="/show.php?nom=123">123</a></li>
<?php } else { ?>
    <li class=""><a href="/show.php?nom=123">123</a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

An alternative using a ternary operator:

```
<li <?php echo ($urlpage == "/show.php?nom=123") ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="/show.php?nom=123">123</a></li>
```

Applying to all pages:

```
<?php $pages = array('123', '456', '789'); ?>
<ul>
    <li <?php echo (!isset($_GET['nom']) ? 'class="active"' : ''); ?>><a href="show.php">Home</a></li>
    <?php foreach($pages as $page): ?>
        <?php if (isset($_GET['nom']) && $_GET['nom'] == $page) { ?>
            <li class="active"><a href="/show.php?nom=<?php echo $page; ?>"><?php echo $page; ?></a></li>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <li class=""><a href="/show.php?nom=<?php echo $page; ?>"><?php echo $page; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: @dotpush its okay to add supplemental info, no need to remove the ternary way as this was an alternative and part of the answer also

Comment: It's not working... It's just not actived! Also, when I click on the link, it's goes to `show.php?name=` but with no 123 or other.

Comment: @Ghost: Oups, sorry. I didn't even saw for the ternary way part removal.

Comment: @dotpush no prob, i have it back its okay

Comment: @InxDev i made revision, you can check it again,

Comment: Tanks a lot! Just change `/show.php?nom=` to `show.php?nom=`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way is to use the $_GET

```
if(isset($_GET['name']))
 if($_GET['name'] == '123') 
  ...
```

and so forth

Comment: Yes, i change to `If ($_GET['name'] == '123')` but I get an error : `Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\cadeau noel\cadeau.php on line 40`. Line 40 -> `If ($_GET['name'] == '123') {`

Comment: What does URL look like? (In your browser)

Comment: Also thats why I suggested to put `if(isset($_GET['name']))` if your URL does not have the ?name=123 or name=124, name=125 etc at the end of the URL, it will just give a warning.

So either earlier in the code add

 `if(!isset($_GET['name'])) $_GET['name'] = '';`

Comment: Tank you, but I used the Ghost answer, it was better.